# How can I run the ARCore three.ar.js examples on a local server and my phone?

Tags: three.js, arcore

I've tried forking and cloning the three.ar.js GitHub repo, then cd'ing in and running 'npm run dev' as suggested in the README, but no matter what I do, I get all kinds of problems. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

`npm install http-server`
run `http-server` in the examples folder.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was just copy the example project to my domain, install the WebARonARCore browser on my phone with ADB, paste the URL to the html file in your webARonARCore browser and it works like a charm.
 I can even do remote debugging with my chrome browser (only seems to work while my android studio is running and the phone is attached via USB ofcourse).

But this is on an external/remote server though. Don't know about local.